# Create instance of Prototype object on the fly with paramters

Tags: java, spring

I need to create prototype scope instance of the object "on the fly" during my code execution.

I know that lookup method would be nice solution:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection

```
<!-- a stateful bean deployed as a prototype (non-singleton) -->
<bean id="command" class="fiona.apple.AsyncCommand" scope="prototype">
<!-- inject dependencies here as required -->
</bean>

<!-- commandProcessor uses statefulCommandHelper -->
<bean id="commandManager" class="fiona.apple.CommandManager">
<lookup-method name="createCommand" bean="command"/>
</bean>
```

Can i set parameter to `createCommand` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, because the container doesn't know what to do with that parameter. What do you expect it to do with it? The lookup method only gets a new instance of the object, getting it from the container. So it has all its dependencies injected before being returned.

If you want to pass an additional argument - you can do that after you obtain the instance. For example:

```
Foo someParam = ...;
CommandManager manager = createCommand();
manager.doSomething(someParam);
```